# How to close a console application by typing EXIT?

Tags: vb.net, console

I have an VB.Net Console Application running and I do not want it to close when the user hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button, rather I want it to close when they type `EXIT` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  What should I do?

Comment: if Michael's answer isn't clear, post the end of your `Main` method and we can look at it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read from the console using [Console.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) (which requires a carriage return to complete).

```
If (Console.ReadLine() = "EXIT") Then
    Environment.Exit(0) 'or, simply return from the Main method
End If
```

Another way to phrase it:

```
While (Not Console.ReadLine() = "EXIT")
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't say the magic word!")
End While
```

Remember that once you return from your `Main` method, your console application closes. It's hard to advise you exactly what to do without seeing the logical structure of your application, but remember: if you want to prevent your application from exiting, don't let your `Main` method return.

Comment: @michael:: Dear Friend Its still not working to my purpose.The moment i hit the ENTER button it is getting closed. Even if I am Not typing the wir EXIT before it.

Comment: @Rajdeep: what happens after that block of code? Once you return from your `Main` method, your console application closes. You'll need to block that. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @Michael :: That will be so nice of you.Waiting for your Edited Reply

Comment: Module Scheduler

    Sub main()




        Dim portno As Integer = 8080
       

        Dim channel As TcpServerChannel = New TcpServerChannel(portno)
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, False)
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(ExactllyLib.Exactlly), "Scheduler", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)

        Console.WriteLine("Start " & "Scheduler mode")
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close " & "Scheduler...")

        If Console.ReadLine = "Exit" Then
            Environment.Exit(0)
        End If


        
    End Sub

Comment: @Rajdeep: add your code to your question, and use the `101010` button to format it. But it looks like some variant of my second example will work for you. Note my last paragraph. What do you want to happen if they type something other than "EXIT"?

Comment: @Michael/Egrunin:: Michael, I got what you are trying to say. According to you until and unless i get my specific word i will keep on executing the main() so that it does not return anything.I did that.I wrote: if Console.ReadLine.Trim.ToUpper <> "EXIT" Then
            Console.WriteLine("")
        End If

Comment: Above code is also not working.All i want is unless and untill user write anything other than "EXIT", the application will not close

Comment: @Rajdeep: you need to use `while`, not `if`. What you're doing now is equivalent to: *if they type "exit", then write an empty line. Then, whether or not they typed "exit", quit.*

Comment: @Michael..In VB.Net '<>' means not equal so i am writting   If Console.ReadLine.Trim.ToUpper <> "EXIT" Then
            Console.WriteLine("")
        End If

Comment: Look into the difference between [if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) and [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx). Again: you want to use `while`, not `if`.

Comment: @Michael..I got your logic..it was my fault..Thankx a lot Michael.

Comment: @michael:: I appreciate your ans and logic.Thanks for your knowledge.Have a nice day

Comment: This code is C#, not VB.NET. I submitted an edit changing it from C# to VB.NET.